# Is there an algorithm to build rectangles by groups of paralle line segments

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I try to find an algo to build all the rectangles by groups of paralle lines. The equations for all the lines are given. Here is an example to explain the situation, which shows two groups of parallel lines and they are perpendicular to each other: (the red lines in group(a) are parallel and the green lines in group(b) are also parallel.)

[image]

The rectangle should be subject to one constrant, that the minimal length of its edge must be bigger than the d_min, see figure. And the rectangles can overlap to each other.

```
Line equation: y = kx + b
struct sLine 
{
  float k;
  float b;
}
// Input
vetor<sLine> vecLineGroupA;
vetor<sLine> vecLineGroupA;

// Output
struct sRectangle
{
  // 4 edges of a rectangle
  sLine  Line1;
  sLine  Line2;
  sLine  Line3;
  sLine  Line4;
}
```

Is there an algo to solve this Problem, or anyone has an idea for that?

Comment: are the rectangles are allowed to overlap? Are you looking for all possible rectangles or only some of them?

Comment: are there only two groups of parallel lines that cross at an angle of 90º (as in the pic) or could there also be non orthogonal lines?

Comment: In which form do you have the equations for the lines? In which form do you need the output for a rectangle? May an rectangle overlap a line? Vector math allows you to calculate the distance between two parallel lines. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: @tobi303 the rectangles are allowed to be overlapped . I try to look for all possibilities.  Non orthogonal lines are not considered.

Comment: The form of equations  is y = kx + b. A rectangle can overlap a line

Comment: Could you express the lines in programming terms? Like: `struct line {double k; double b;}; vector<line> groupA {.....};` or whatever you have. Like wise for output format

Comment: @4386427 I have edited

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have something like:

```
// line: y = ax + b;
struct line {double a; double b;};

vector<line> groupA = {....};     
vector<line> groupB = {.....};
```

you'll need some thing like this pseudo code:

```
sort_with_smallest_b_first(groupA);
sort_with_smallest_b_first(groupB);

for (int n1=0; n1 < groupA.size()-1; ++n1)
{
   for (int n2=n1+1; n2 < groupA.size(); ++n2)
   {
       for (int j1=0; j1 < groupB.size()-1; ++j1)
       { 
           for (int j2=j1+1; j2 < groupB.size(); ++j2)
           { 
               // Now you have the recatangle between the lines
               // groupA[n1], groupA[n2]
               // groupB[j1], groupB[j2]
               double d1 = distance(groupA[n1], groupA[n2]);
               double d2 = distance(groupB[j1], groupB[j2]);
               if (d1 >= dmin && d2 >= dmin)
               {
                   // Add rectangle to output
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

For calculating distance between lines see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

If performance is an issue you can improve performance by first calculating all non-overlapping rectangles and then create the overlapping rectangles from the group of non-overlapping rectangles. It will save you some distance calculations, i.e. as you do a simple add of the distance from the non-overlapping rectangles instead of always recalculating using the "complex" formula.

Comment: A good solution.  There might be one problem that it includes 4 times" for Loop",  it might be slow

Comment: @rayallen - since the rectangles can overlap it's necessary